# Vue Router $route does not exist when compiling in Vue 3, TypeScript with Webpack Encore

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, symfony, webpack-encore

I've been trying to get vue-router `$route` setup within my `shims.vue.d.ts` file to allow for $route to not throw an error on `this` scope.  `this.$route.params.paymentId` keeps coming back with type error `TS2339: Property '$route' does not exist on type 'void'`.

I am using `<script setup lang="ts">`. In other defined components(https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#definecomponent) I have, it references and builds fine. I just can't seem to figure out how get it working with Vue3 `<script setup lang="ts">`.

Below is my current `shims.vue.d.ts` and structure after trying to define in numerous ways. I have enabled `.enableTypeScriptLoader()` in `webpack.config.js`

```
// myComponent.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, onMounted } from "vue";

const paymentId = this.$route.params.paymentId;

</script>
```

```
declare module '*.vue' {
    import { ComponentOptions } from 'vue'
    const ComponentOptions: ComponentOptions
    export default ComponentOptions
}


declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    import type {Router, RouteLocationNormalized } from "vue-router";

    interface Vue {
        $router: Router,
        $route: RouteLocationNormalized
    }
}
```

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules"
  ],
  "include": ["**/*.ts","/**/*.tx","**/*.vue"]
}
```

Comment: use `this` isn't a thing anymore with Composition API.  I advise consulting the official [vue-router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#accessing-the-router-and-current-route-inside-setup) which goes over how to use router with composition API (the docs use `setup()` but the router syntax using `script setup` is the same)

Comment: Thank you I totally forgot about that in the composition API. Well that solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I forgot that `this` isn't a thing anymore with Composition API. After updating the script setup all works fine.

```
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()
const route = useRoute()
```